# Netscape Incorrectly Renders Floating Share Bar

Tags: css, netscape

I have been experimenting by adding a floating social media share bar to my web page.

The bar renders perfectly in I.E, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari, but refuses to behave when viewed in Netscape Navigator 9.

It's important for the bar to render properly in all of the above, and thought the problem might perhaps be due to something else on my web page interfering with its correct operation.  However, when I test the bar using the mock up page I have posted a link to here, the same problem still exists.

Can anyone suggest what alterations I might make to the source code in order for this problem to be overcome?

Here's a link to my demo page.

http://www.corncreations.co.uk/test/floating_bar.html

Here's a link to the creators page, which includes the source code.

http://www.myblogger-tricks.com/2013/09/add-awesome-floating-sharing-bar-on.html

Any constructive advice gratefully received.

The code used for the demo is available by visiting the second of the links (above), but anyway, here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">
#floating_bar {
background-color:#fff;
position:fixed;
padding:0 0 3px 0;
bottom: 30%;
margin-left:-60px;
float:left;
border: 1px dotted #f7f7f7;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
z-index:10;
}

#floating_bar {
clear:both;
}
</style>
<div id='floating_bar'>
<div style='margin:10px 0 5px 13px;' id='like'>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="40" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
<div style='margin:0px 0 0 10px;' id='gplusone'>
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
</div>

<div style='margin:5px 5px 5px 6px;'>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="mybloggertriks" data-lang="en" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
<div style='margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;' id='linkedin'>
<script src='http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script data-counter='top' type='IN/Share'></script>
</div>
<div style='margin:0 0 10px 11px; id='su'>
<script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=5"></script>
</div>
<p style='line-height:0px; margin-bottom:8px; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.myblogger-tricks.com/2013/09/add-awesome-floating-sharing-bar-on.html' rel='nofollow' style='color:#333;'> Get Widget</a></p>
</div>
```

As to what I've researched and tried so far - I've read other posts on this forum, and also Googled for an answer, but apart from reading a few posts elsewhere from others having difficulty with their Facebook Like buttons not rendering properly in Netscape, nothing else seemed relevant.  I haven't tried altering the original source code yet, as I am not sure what to do that might correct the problem.

Comment: Netscape? Did you just say, Netscape?

Comment: "Any constructive advice gratefully received."
Yes 
Don't use NetScape and catch up with modern technology.

Comment: Please include code to repro this in the question, so this thread will remain useful to others after you've fixed your site. In addition it would help if you tell us what you've researched and tried so far.

Comment: Hey c'mon everyone, as of the end of 2006, Netscape still had around 0.1% market share. Unfortunately I can't find any stats past then...

Comment: As these comments suggest, you really (and I mean _really_) don't need to worry about supporting Netscape Navigator. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator): "AOL stopped development of Netscape Navigator on December 28, 2007, but continued supporting the web browser with security updates until March 1, 2008."

Comment: All present views and opinions accepted, but would still be good to understand why Netscape fails to render the bar in the same way as all the other main browsers.

Comment: @aitch probably because it's an ancient web browser that hasn't been updated to modern specs.

Comment: The short answer is most likely "because it doesn't correctly implement the CSS/HTML standard". That's not surprising since the browser is so dated. Identifying the problem more accurately would probably be very time-consuming (besides needing to get hold of NS, we'd also need to pull the page apart one tag at a time to track it down). In short, it's kind of like asking why something didn't work on a ZX spectrum. I'm sure there is an answer but finding it would take considerable effort for very little benefit (beyond satisfying your curiosity of course). That said, I wish you good luck

Answer (score 7):

### 1. There's a point when backwards compatibility goes too far.

> why Netscape fails to render the bar in the same way as all the other main browsers

You're implying that Netscape is a "main browser" like the browsers you mentioned in your question. Netscape used to have a [significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Netscape-navigator-usage-data.svg) market share, but its time has passed (see [History of the web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_web_browser) on Wikipedia, specifically the timeline chart at the bottom of the article; Also [Usage share of web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) for current statistics).

**It makes the question irrelevant from a practical standpoint. It's hard to justifying the question let alone finding an answer, given that you're attempting to support a legacy browser.**

But let's assume you have a valid reason for supporting a browser that is virtually extinct...

### 2. What is the problem?

> "The bar ... refuses to behave"

You might as well be saying, "it doesn't work". **How** doesn't it work? What is the **expected behavior**, and how is the actual result deviating from your expectation? You shouldn't expect us to download a browser that hardly anybody has used for over a decade to confirm an ambiguous bug description ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

### 3. Your HTML is funky

- **No formatting** The lack of indentation isn't a technical concern (only a nitpick), but makes it hard to read
- **Inconsistent use of quotes** The general practice is to use double quotes `"` for HTML attributes. For example: `<div id="floating_bar">`.
- **Is that `!` supposed to be there in the `<script/>` tag?
- `<g:plusone/>` is not a valid HTML tag. Were you trying to do something like [this](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#google-plus1)?
- The CSS is probably not working because the `bottom` property is set as a percentage. Support for bottom/right was pretty spotty at first, and percentage might be iffy.

Comment: This isn't really a very good answer; most of what you've written should have been put as comments. However, your very last line salvages it, as it is a good attempt at pinpointing the issue. For that alone, and for taking the time to write an answer at all, +1.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the `!` in the javascript code is perfectly valid; it's a way of getting the function to auto-run. Fairly common technique, although I agree it doesn't help readability. There are other techniques for doing the same thing which are easier to read, but this is commonly used for minified code, as it's the shortest number of characters required to achieve auto-running a function.